# What exactly does "reusable" mean for angular directives?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Sometimes I see the adjective "reusable" used to describe angular directives. It's somewhat confusing because sometimes it implies reusability across YOUR app, and sometimes it means across ALL apps. If it's the latter, wouldn't there exist a large repository of directives already created by other people thus making the probability that you have to write your own directive quite small? (e.g. hundreds of directives as useful as ng-model or ng-show)

Would it be correct to assume the inter-app reusability requires directives with `scope: true`, while "global" reusability uses isolate scope?

The way I'm currently writing directives is rather app specific, they mostly just package complex repeated html (w/ variables passed through using isolate scope) using templates and transclusion but I feel like "real" directives are ones like ng-model. So just wondering if there are 2 meanings behind "reusable", one which allows you to make super generic directives useable everywhere and others that are "semi-reusable" that help keep your code neat but are too application specific for use anywhere else.

Comment: github is that large repo of reusable directives.  lots of good ones are listed here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/JsFiddle-Examples

Comment: @j.wittwer Cool list!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that most of your directives won't be reusable in other apps, since most of them will contain some logic specific to your app. But it's still a great benefit to be able to reuse your directives inside your app, or in other apps you've created that has the same app logic.

Directives that are reusable in different apps tend to be stuff like tabs, maps, autocomplete, etc. If your looking for UI widgets like that, [AngularUI](http://angular-ui.github.io/) is a good place to look.

You don't have to use `scope: true` in your directive for them to be reusable. `ng-model` for example is very reusable (between different apps), but it doesn't have an isolated scope. The case for setting `scope: true` is when you develop a directive that needs to add properties on the scope, and you ask for an isolated scope to avoid the risk of having your scope properties clash with the scope properties of the template using the directive.

Comment: Thanks, that cleared some things up! I was just making sure I wasn't getting "good" at creating directives the "wrong" way.

Comment: Just to add more to my understanding. I believe that any directive can be written with any type of scope (either false,child, or isolate) Using false is equivalent to using global variables, possible, but potentially unsafe. Using isolate scopes require every variable passed through to be declared explicitly but is safest, you can make everything an isolate scope but it would be similar to making each js file you write its own module. Child scopes (scope:true) are a decent middle ground that mimics the js proto- chain, it's like isolate but with all parent attributes passed through by default.

Comment: I wouldn't say that not setting an isolated scope is the same as using global variables. There can certainly be use cases for not having an isolated scope, you just have to be really careful not to override someone else scope property. But the main reasons for not having an isolated scope is that it's cheaper (not something you'd really need to think about unless your creating hundreds/thousands of instances), or that you need to communicate with the templates scope like `ng-model` does. But my guess is that most of the directives you'll end up writing will have an isolated scope.

Comment: I agree! I didn't mean "exactly" like global variables, just abstractly/philosphically similar in that it's easier but you need to be more careful.